# scrolling through an element in python3+selenium with chrome webdriver on google maps

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scroll through some reviews on a restaurant in google maps using selenium chrome webdriver, say Nobu Palo Alto here:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Nobu+Palo+Alto/@37.4437223,-122.1637038,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m11!1m3!2m2!1srestaurants!6e5!3m6!1s0x0:0x5bb11772add3928!8m2!3d37.4437179!4d-122.1615154!9m1!1b1

I used this function which seems to get (and print) the javascript height, but instead of infinite scrolling it just breaks after printing the last height == new height, but I know there are more reviews it's not loading:

```
def __init__(self, site):
    self.site=site
    self.option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    self.option.add_argument("-incognito")
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/me/Documents/project/chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=self.option)

def scroll(self):
    self.browser.get(self.site)
    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 4
    sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    # Get scroll height
    last_height = self.browser.execute_script("return document.querySelector('#pane > div > div.widget-pane-content.scrollable-y > div > div > div.section-listbox.section-scrollbox.scrollable-y.scrollable-show').scrollHeight")
    print("last height = " + str(last_height))

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        self.browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.querySelector('#pane > div > div.widget-pane-content.scrollable-y > div > div > div.section-listbox.section-scrollbox.scrollable-y.scrollable-show').scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = self.browser.execute_script("return document.querySelector('#pane > div > div.widget-pane-content.scrollable-y > div > div > div.section-listbox.section-scrollbox.scrollable-y.scrollable-show').scrollHeight")
        print("new height = " + str(new_height))
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to scroll through using the javascript to load the review.

Here is the simple script to load the number of review you need.

```
reviewCount = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='section-review ripple-container']"))
# loading a minimum of 50 reviews
while reviewCount <50: #<=== change this number based on your requirement
    # load the reviews
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'section-loading-spinner')]").location_once_scrolled_into_view 
    # wait for loading the reviews
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='section-loading-overlay-spinner'][@style='display:none']")))
    # get the reviewsCount
    reviewCount = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='section-review ripple-container']"))
```

Comment: I think this approach is better than what I was thinking, going to use this going forward. Thanks a ton!